# Writing a function that can accept any number of arguments in C

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double average ( int num, ... )
{
    va_list arguments;                     
    double sum = 0;
    int x;
    /* Initializing arguments to store all values after num */
    va_start ( arguments, num );        
    //printf("arguments = %d...........num = %d",arguments,num);
    for(x = 0; x < num; x++ )        
    {
        sum += va_arg ( arguments, double ); 
    }
    va_end ( arguments );                  // Cleans up the list
    return sum / num;                      
}

int main()
{
   printf( "Average 2 = %f\n", average ( 3, 12.2, 22.3, 4.5 ) );
   printf( "Average 3 = %f\n", average ( 5, 3.3, 2.2, 1.1, 5.5, 3.3 ) );
   printf( "Average 4 = %f\n", average ( 9, 3.3, 2.2, 1.1, 5.5, 3.3, 
       3.10, 13.3, 143.312, 39.35 ) );
}
```

Here we are using:- `va_start ( arguments, num );`

> What is arguments contain here ? I am confused with this.
>   When I tried to print it, I am not getting the values that I passed as an argument. Please explain

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: We know about Variadic functions. This isn't a blog site, what is the question?

Comment: I had a question but now have answer also, So posting it with answer

Comment: Lots of resources do already exist on that topic.

Comment: This is clear plagiarism from the external site that could be googled in two seconds. What point in posting it here?

Comment: We are glad you found the answer, so there is no need to post a question (rather I don't see a question at all) for which you already have an answered. This is likely to be deleted.

Comment: Also, while it's nice to be able to write `average(1, 2.3, 4)`, this has little use in practice, where your data is usually availale as array, which you can't convert to an argument list. This is not a good example of when to use variadic functions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. You are explicitly allowed to [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) a question. But it must meet the site requirements: there must be a question at the top (without the answer) and a separate answer below (usually without most of the question). So, you need to edit your question so it contains just the question, and you need to add an answer that contains the answer. Is there another question on SO about "How to handle a counted but variable number of arguments?"? When is it better to use a count and an array?

Comment: @MOehm Well technically you could push them to the stack in the loop. But it hardly could be perceived as a good method)

Comment: @Smita So, you have an answer you don't understand? Then post a question *about exactly that*. There's no need to give a whole lecture about variadic functions --- and then forgetting to put the actual question...

Comment: In `va_start(arguments, num);`, `arguments` is of the type `va_list`, more precisely uninitialized object of type `va_list`.  It carries the information needed to retrieve the additional arguments using `va_arg`

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Oh, she deleted the question right-away :D

Comment: I think it can be a duplicate after she has edited it, but definitely not Unclear now. Consider reopening it, and then may be close it off as a duplicate if it is. @Felix ?

Comment: I think being blunt with new users is not appropriate. guide them in kind way should be the solution like @Jonathan did.

Comment: @shami closing it was the correct way and yes, now it's in a shape for reopening. I don't even think it's a duplicate, asking specifically about what va_list *is*

Comment: "I am not getting the values that I passed as an argument."  --> Post the incorrect values you did get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning your question: You should not care what `arguments` really contains, because that depends on your host architecture and the implementation of your compiler. Typically, it could be a pointer to the location on the stack where the next argument can be found, but it could be anything else, too.

The idea behind `va_list` and the macros around it is to provide a consistent API that you can use *in the same way* on any architecture to get the arguments, without having to know how they are handled internally. `va_list` therefore is what you call a *black box* (use it through its API, don't look inside). Just rely on `va_init()` and `va_arg()` to fetch the arguments from it.

Comment: Thank you ! But I really don't want to rely on it. I want to know how they are handled internally.

Comment: [Refer here](http://blog.aaronballman.com/2012/06/how-variable-argument-lists-work-in-c/) if this is just out of being curious. There's an example implementation for x86. It gets very "hairy" on amd64 because arguments there are passed in CPU registers. For any **serious** program, accept `va_list` as what it is: a blackbox that just does what you expect.

Comment: What if I want to write my own printf function say myPrintf(). How could I write it ?

Comment: That's probably just a bad idea, because it's really complex. You basically have to parse the format string, looking for `%` sequences and when you find one, get an argument of matching type from `va_arg()`, convert it as specified to string and append it ...

Comment: There's a [very limited implementation in linux' x86 boot code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/boot/printf.c) which I looked at to create [my implementation for my MS-DOS .COM runtime](https://github.com/Zirias/clang-libdos/blob/master/src/stdio/stdio_printf.c) (also quite limited) -- If you're really in a situation where you NEED to implement your own `printf()` -- start cursing